# WOL stops working after booting Ubuntu

Tags: wakeonlan

After preparing my P5K Motherboard to recieve WOL Magic Packets, following [this](http://tips.timscomputer.com/archives/166) tutorial, I shutdown and booted several times to Windows.

The problem happens when I shutdown from Ubuntu.
It simply won't boot.
The output of `ethtool eth0` and part of `lspci` is on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/g0zKec8r) but here are the important parts:

**sudo ethtool eth0**

```
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: g
            Current message level: 0x0000003f (63)
                                   drv probe link timer ifdown ifup
```

**lspci**

```
2:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. Attansic L1 Gigabit Ethernet (rev b0)
```

I must say that if i boot to windows and shutdown *without making any changes* the WOL works correctly again.

Comment: please repeat the `ethtool` command using sudo and update your answer.

Comment: ok it seems like with sudo the problem was solved.

Comment: After executing the command 

    `sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol g`

and shutting-down Ubuntu problem solved.. i can boot from a shutdown from Windows or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## If the interface is managed by the system

If your network interface (`eth0` in most cases) is managed via /etc/network/interfaces you could avoid running ethtool before every shutdown by [following this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan#Enabling_WoL_in_the_NIC).

## If the interface is managed by NetworkManager

If `eth0` is managed by Network Manager, the simplest way is to add the `ethtool -s eth0 wol g` command in an `if-up.d script`.

Here is a quick example that you could put in `/etc/network/if-up.d/eth0-wol` *and* make the script executable: `sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/eth0-wol` :

```
#!/bin/sh

ETHTOOL=/sbin/ethtool
[ -x "$ETHTOOL" ] || exit 0
[ "$IFACE" != "lo" ] || exit 0

WOL="g"
"$ETHTOOL" -s "$IFACE" wol "$WOL"
exit 0
```

Comment: also https://wiki.debian.org/WakeOnLan

Comment: also https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2394211

Answer (score 1):

In some cases on Ubuntu 12.10 the output of `sudo ethtool eth0` gives the following output

```
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
                   drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
Cannot get link status: Operation not permitted
```

What I did to solve this I activated the root account on my computer via `sudo passwd root` and then afterwards logged as root user executed `ethtool -s eth0 wol g` which solved the WOL issue in my case.

Comment: It's not necessary to log in as root for this. Just run `sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol g`. In instances where you need a root shell, you *still* don't need to log in as root, just use `sudo -s`. In instances where you need a root *login* shell, *even then* you need not log in as root, as you can use `sudo -i` instead. See [the community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) for details. If you have enabled the root account and wish to disable it (either because you don't need it enabled anymore or, far more likely, because you never really had to), run: `sudo passwd -dl root`