# How to change Wake-on Lan settings?

Tags: networking, 16.04

I have problems with wired internet connection.

```
ifconfig
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:4d:7b:31:40:67  
          inet addr:10.129.45.123  Bcast:10.129.63.255  Mask:255.255.224.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ae56:1e47:3b4f:9147/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:94 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:42 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6204 (6.2 KB)  TX bytes:6856 (6.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:628 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:628 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:48976 (48.9 KB)  TX bytes:48976 (48.9 KB)
```

And this is what I get with ethtool

```
ethtool enp3s0
Settings for enp3s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                         1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

With sudo, just two lines are changed

```
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
```

What does this mean?

How to change my wol settings?
[WOL stops working after booting Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190898/wol-stops-working-after-booting-ubuntu/190944#190944)

Should I change script from the above link?

Comment: Is it turned on in the BIOS/Network Card itself?

Comment: @Ziazis I do not know,how to see this?

Comment: During a boot go into the BIOS settings via the shortkey that is provided. The same goes for an external Network card if you have one. There should be an option if available, usually in the category "power" or something like that. Since every BIOS is a little different you have to look through it and see if you can find it. Another option you can just try `sudo ethtool enp3s0` so you have permission to see the wol options.

Comment: @Ziazis I think that I have UEFI on my desktop.

Comment: Wake on: g usually means wakeonlan is enabled.

Comment: ^what muru said. If you want to turn it off `sudo ethtool -s enp3s0 wol d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use WoL features you first need to make sure that it is enabled in your BIOS/Network Card.

If it is enabled you can use the `ethtool` to check the current settings of it.

If you are missing ethtool you can install it via `sudo apt install ethtool`.

Once you have it available you can check your settings via this command:

`sudo ethtool [yourInterface]` e.g. `sudo ethtool enp0s3`

Look for the line `Wake-on: d`

If the value is "d" you can enable it with this command:

`sudo ethtool -s [yourInterface] wol g` e.g. `sudo ethtool -s enp0s3 wol g`

If the value is "g" you can disable it via:

`sudo ethtool -s [yourInterface] wol d` e.g. `sudo ethtool -s enp0s3 wol d`