# Ethtool Wake-on Lan is disabled after reboot

Tags: networking, wakeonlan, systemd-networkd

I followed [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan) guide to enable wake on lan on my Ubuntu Server 22.04 installation.
I even put

```
iface eno1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.5
    up ethtool -s eno1 wol g
```

to `/etc/network`. No matter what I try, after rebooting, wake-on-lan is disabled again:
`Wake-on: d` when checking with `sudo ethtool eno1`.

I even tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/190944), in case my network is managed by network manager, but I think it's not:

```
$ sudo service network-manager status
Unit network-manager.service could not be found.
```

Comment: This worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1051894/243321

Comment: @OrganicMarble this would be a soulution, if I would use network manager, or am I wrong? Anyway, it does not work for me

Comment: The `/etc/network/interfaces` method is deprecated in Ubuntu 17.10 and later. Please make your changes in netplan. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2394211

Comment: Thanks @chili555 this works