# My Office computer keeps going into a deep sleep since upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ssh, suspend, 22.04

I want to be able to wake up my office computer with ssh when it is in sleeping mode.

Before the last update of Ubuntu 22.04, It was working like a charm. But now my computer is going into a strange deep sleep. I need to be physically there and use the power button to wake it up (it won't work with my keyboard, my mouse, or through ssh).

I tried to change the sleeping settings to avoid the computer going to this mode with

`$ sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`

But the computer still goes to sleep.

Comment: similar question asked here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424675/wake-on-lan-broken-after-22-04-update. And also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425425/ethtool-wake-on-lan-is-disabled-after-reboot

Comment: It finally worked after multiple reboot